# How to rotate the shapes in a tangram game without using `context.rotate`

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

in canvas 600 * 600
the three points of trangle is (100, 100), (300, 100), (200,200)
center of rotation is (200, 100)

I want to realize draging the trangle to rotate. but I don't know how to change the coordinates of these points.

ps: I have know how to calculate the angle of rotation
var rotateRadian = Math.atan2(mouseY - center.y, mouseX - center.x) - Math.atan2(startDragPosition.y - center.y, startDragPosition.x - center.x);

**[ Additional information from a comment below ]**

I want to build a tangram, there are rectangle、triangle and parallelogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have a good start!**

[image]

First calculate the mouse-to-centerpoint angle:

```
// calc mouse angle
var dx=mouseX-centerX;
var dy=mouseY-centerY;
radianAngle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
```

Since you have an equilateral triangle, your triangle is a regular polygon. Use trigonometry to calculate the 3 rotated points of your polygon:

```
// vertex#1
var x1=cx+radius*Math.cos(rotationAngle);
var y1=cy+radius*Math.sin(rotationAngle);

// vertex#2
rotationAngle+=PI2/3;
var x2=cx+radius*Math.cos(rotationAngle);
var y2=cy+radius*Math.sin(rotationAngle);

// vertex#3
rotationAngle+=PI2/3;
var x3=cx+radius*Math.cos(rotationAngle);
var y3=cy+radius*Math.sin(rotationAngle);
```

Then just listen for mousemove events and redraw the triangle accordingly:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
var $canvas=$("#canvas");
var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
var scrollX=$canvas.scrollLeft();
var scrollY=$canvas.scrollTop();
ctx.fillStyle='red';
ctx.strokeStyle='blue';
ctx.lineWidth=2;

var isDown=false;
var startX;
var startY;

var PI2=Math.PI*2;
var cx=150;
var cy=150;
var sideLength=50;
var originalAngle=0;
var radius=sideLength*Math.sqrt(3)/3;

draw(200,200);

$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});


function draw(mx,my){

  //
  var dx=mx-cx;
  var dy=my-cy;
  var currentAngle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
  var rotationAngle=currentAngle-originalAngle;
  // vertex#1
  var x1=cx+radius*Math.cos(rotationAngle);
  var y1=cy+radius*Math.sin(rotationAngle);
  // vertex#2
  rotationAngle+=PI2/3;
  var x2=cx+radius*Math.cos(rotationAngle);
  var y2=cy+radius*Math.sin(rotationAngle);
  // vertex#3
  rotationAngle+=PI2/3;
  var x3=cx+radius*Math.cos(rotationAngle);
  var y3=cy+radius*Math.sin(rotationAngle);

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
  ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
  ctx.lineTo(x3,y3);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x1,y1,3,0,PI2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();

}


function handleMouseMove(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mx=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  my=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  draw(mx,my);

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>The triangle will rotate according to the mouse</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

**[ Addition based on questioners comment ]**

The math is the similar, but more complicated because tangram shapes are not regular.

For each shape you need to:

*Find the shape's centroid which is it's center of rotation*

```
cx=average of all x vertices. 
cy=average of all y vertices.
```

*Find the shape's 3 or 4 radial lengths*

```
// for each radius
radial length=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(vx-cx,2)+Math.pow(vy-cy,2))
```

*Find the shape's 3 or 4 radial angles*

```
// for each radius
radial angle=Math.atan2(Math.pow(vy-cy,2),Math.pow(vx-cx,2))
```

*Now use the same trigonometry in my answer to rotate the vertices around the centroid*

Comment: Great, in your example, your triangle is a regular polygon. you can calculate the angle by "rotationAngle+=PI2/3"; but in my current project, I want to build a tangram, there are rectangle、triangle and parallelogram. I can't use "rotationAngle += PI2/3" anymore...Can you help me?

Comment: Really?! Your question asks nothing about a tangram! The math is the similar, but more complicated because tangram shapes are not regular. I've added to my answer to explain the additional math.